# Android SQLite database update method

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, where-clause

Maybe this question has been answered but I cannot find it, so:

In SQLiteDatabase update method,

```
int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

What will happen if the WHERE clause does not exists?. I mean does not return any row,
it will perform a normal insert, or do nothing?

**EDIT**

I think I did not explain it correctly.

Suppose this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE weight (weight REAL, date TEXT);

INSERT INTO weight VALUES (78.5,"10/03/2013");
INSERT INTO weight VALUES (68.5,"09/03/2013");
INSERT INTO weight VALUES (79.5,"08/03/2013");
```

And now suppose this code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("weight", 90.2);
db.update("weight",values, "date = '15/03/2013'",null);
```

NOTICE that there is no row with date = '15/03/2013' so, what happen in that case (that was what I wanted to mean) it will insert or do nothing?

Comment: Thanks @Pragnani I didn't notice that.

Comment: It says right in the docs for the parameter 'whereClause' http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: You should delete this question now

Comment: updated answer, check once..@J.Arenas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

**It will check is there a row with date = '15/03/2013 if there is no row, 
then no rows will effect, and the update method will  return 0**

---

If I understand your question,
Where claus  is optional, it may be null, if you don't provide where clause it will update all the rows in a table.

It is just a sql thing, like if you don't supply where condition it will update all rows.
documentation clearly says that,

Parameters

**whereClause   the optional WHERE clause to apply when updating. Passing null will update all rows.**

[SqlliteData Update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use the `WHERE` clause [all the records on the table will be affected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

**whereClause** the optional WHERE clause to apply when updating. Passing null will update all rows.